# JFrame not Executing! (Eclipse Editor)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

My JFrame isn't executing or not even showing up when I press the run button. I am sure my code is right(Please Check) and I guess it could be an Eclipse Bug. Help would be Appreciated!

Eclipse Version: Neon

OS: Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CreateServer {

    public static JFrame start= new JFrame("TRDServerCreator");

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       CreateServer.startwin();
    }

    public static void startwin ()
    {
        start.setSize(500,500);
        start.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        start.setResizable(false);

        JPanel cont= new JPanel();
        start.add(cont);

        JLabel n1=new JLabel("Thank you for choosing TRD Server Creator");
        n1.setVisible(true);
        JLabel n2=new JLabel("Pls select the Verison of your New Server");
        n2.setVisible(true);
        cont.add(n1,n2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to make the JFrame visible.  Also, you need to add your JLabels one at a time;  the second argument to the add method is a constraint, not another child component.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just add `start.setVisible(true);`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CreateServer {

    public static JFrame start= new JFrame("TRDServerCreator");

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       CreateServer.startwin();
    }

    public static void startwin ()
    {
        start.setSize(500,500);
        start.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        start.setResizable(false);

        JPanel cont= new JPanel();
        start.add(cont);

        JLabel n1=new JLabel("Thank you for choosing TRD Server Creator");
        n1.setVisible(true);
        JLabel n2=new JLabel("Pls select the Verison of your New Server");
        n2.setVisible(true);
        cont.add(n1,n2);

        start.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: [show() is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show--).  No one should ever call it.

Comment: Oh now it worked but before I added that and did'nt work. I thought its .setVisible() but thanks anyways